# Where can I find rust test binary for my project?

Tags: rust

I'm having problem on a specific function of a test of a specific file:

```
mod test {
//...

 #[test]
    #[cfg(feature = "proto-igmp")]
    fn test_handle_igmp() {
```

I've found here https://github.com/rust-lang/cargo/issues/1407 that I can test specific tests by passing its name as an argument to the test binary. But where's such binary? And can I make `println` work inside tests?

I want to run `test_handle_igmp` to print some things and see why the error is happening.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can find it in `target/$MODE/$NAME-$hash`, e.g. `target/debug/example-3beac917983bc7e3.exe`. Note that there might be multiple ones, some for doc tests, some for `#[test]` functions.

That being said if you just want to run `test_handle_igmp`, you can just use

```
cargo test test_handle_igmp -- --nocapture
```

to run your test and see the `println` outputs. See `cargo test --help` or [the online documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/commands/cargo-test.html).